# .cmd download turns into .cmd.txt when dowloading from browser

Tags: html, download, href

So, I'm trying to link a script download to my Co's helpdesk with

```
<a href="downloads/blackiceremoval.cmd" download="blackiceremoval.cmd">HERE</a>
```

and every time I hit the download link the file downloads as

```
 blackiceremoval.cmd.txt
```

The content itself is perfect inside the file, so it's not a bad link. Now, it's not a big problem to the rest of the IT team, as we can just remove the .txt, but I would like the script to download ready for use. Any ideas?

Comment: This works for me on Chrome, even though I get a warning message whether I want to `keep` the file or discard` it. Keeping it gives me the file as a `.cmd` itself.

Comment: I was able to get your result when I launched chrome manually instead of notepad + +. Doesnt make any sense, but thanks any ways!

Comment: It might be a security feature and makes sense because if any external could launch Chrome and have it download an executable file, then it would be really easy for an infected computer to download harmful files by just launching a link in Chrome without the user doing it.